# Summing every third record grouped by three fields

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a database where the travel times are segmented by epochs and are done on a 5 minute bin, that I need to summation up to 15 minutes. This is tricky because the data is segment by a TMC value, a date, and epoch. None of which are unique. As such:

```
TMC         DATE    EPOCH   Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES
111N20176   7012015 64      63
111N20176   7012015 76      112
111N20176   7012015 80      114
111N20176   7012015 83      127
111N20176   7012015 91      58
111N20176   7012015 93      117
```

I need the first three travel times to be added together, then the next three, and then the next three, and so on.

```
select *, sum(Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES) over (order by EPOCH rows between 3 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg 
 from [dbo].[FHWA_2015_weekend] 
 WHERE TMC = '113P12373' order by DATE, EPOCH
```

Comment: "none of which [individually] are unique" - but they are when considered collectively.

Comment: Oddly, this was tagged mysql.

Comment: This is not MySQL code.  Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: I am using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (as the question was originally tagged), you can enumerate the data using variables and then do the aggregation.

For your sample data this should work:

```
select tmc, date, sum(Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES)
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by date, epoch
     ) t
group by tmc, date, floor((@rn - 1) / 3);
```

In almost any other database, you would use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
select tmc, date, sum(Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date, epoch) as rn
      from t
     ) t
group by tmc, date, floor((rn - 1) / 3);
```